# Details of certificate used to encrypt email received by Outlook

Tags: outlook, encryption

Is there a way of seeing the details of the certificate used to encrypt an email that was received by Outlook.

I'm trying to diagnose an issue and want to see if someone has an out of date offline address book and so is using old certificates.

Note that its not my certificate that I am using to encrypt / sign I need details of - its the one that was used by the person sending to me

Answer (score 0):

Do you use S/MIME?

If using S/MIME, the certificate for encryption is usually installed under “Current User” – “Personal” certificate store, check it on the client side.

If use Outlook normally, the certificate is hosted on server side, you could check the certificate information on the server .

Comment: Its not my certificate that I am using to encrypt / sign I need details of - its the one that was used by the person sending to me